# Is the use of jsfiddle allowed to show config or code?

Tags: discussion

On SO, the use of jsfiddle, or similar, is not allowed as a sole source of code or configuration when asking a question. The code must be within the question itself. I can't find policy for this here.

The issue is that the code on a third party site can be changed or go dead and make the question and answers useless.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. We expect all information needed to understand a question to be in the body of the question, yes. Is that what you mean? That does include code. Posting here with a link to your github or whatever and "please look at my code" would not be considered acceptable.

Comment: @terdon Yes, that is what I mean. I saw a question today that only links to a github account. I will comment on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a general policy that posts should be self contained<sup>1</sup>. If I need to open another page to understand your question or your answer, then it isn't a good one.

Now, there are obvious exceptions such as log files of several thousand lines, but in general we do expect a post to contain all information necessary in order to understand it.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Although it might be an unwritten policy; I can't find anything about it either. If so, consider this the official stance of the moderation team at least.</sub>